# Trying to debug my dotnet 5 WPF app and getting an error: "The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event."

Tags: c#, .net-core

This is dotnet 5 WPF app that was converted from a dotnet framework app using [this tool from Microsoft.](https://github.com/dotnet/try-convert#:%7E:text=%20%EE%80%80try-convert%EE%80%81%20.%20This%20is%20a%20simple%20tool,sure%20to%20update%3A%20%EE%80%80dotnet%EE%80%81%20tool%20update%20-g%20%EE%80%80try-convert%EE%80%81)

The full error says

> The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core.
> The program '[20316] MPRegWpf.exe' has exited with code -2147450740 (0x8000808c).

I am using `Visual Studio 2019 16.11.5`.

Here is the output of `dotnet --info`:

```
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   6.0.100-rc.2.21505.57
 Commit:    ab39070116

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.22000
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100-rc.2.21505.57\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 6.0.0-rc.2.21480.5
  Commit:  6b11d64e7e

.NET SDKs installed:
  3.1.301 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.414 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.100-preview.5.21302.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.100-rc.1.21463.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.100-rc.2.21505.57 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.24 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.27 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.24 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.27 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.18 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.0-rc.2.21480.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.24 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.27 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.30 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.18 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.0-rc.2.21480.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.18 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.19 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.20 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.0-rc.2.21501.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Here is my `.csproj` file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>true</ImportWindowsDesktopTargets>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationIcon>myPassLogoHeader.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Assets\yk05.PNG" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\yk06.PNG" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\yk07.PNG" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\yk08.PNG" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\yk09.PNG" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\yk10.PNG" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\yk11.PNG" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\yk12.PNG" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\yubikey01.png" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\badge_or_mypass.png" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\MFA_bg_withKey.png" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\badge3.png" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\pBar_3.png" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\pBar_5.png" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\pBar_2.png" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\bye.png" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\mpLoad.gif" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\alert.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyPassEnrollment\MyPassEnrollment.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <WCFMetadata Include="Connected Services\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="myPassLogoHeader.ico" />
    <Resource Include="FodyWeavers.xml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Resource>
    <Resource Include="myPassLogoChipOnly %281%29.ico" />
    <Resource Include="myPassLogoChipOnly.ico" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\myPassLogo.png" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\LivIT. LLNL.png" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\blueArrow.png" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\myPassLogoHeader.png" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\phone.png" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\check2.png" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\x2.png" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\yk13_2.png" />
    <Resource Include="Assets\yk15_2.PNG" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Archived Pages\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CommonServiceLocator">
      <Version>2.0.6</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="ControlzEx">
      <Version>5.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Costura.Fody">
      <Version>5.6.0</Version>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Gu.Wpf.FlipView">
      <Version>2.0.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="LLNL-MyPass">
      <Version>1.19.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="MaterialDesignThemes">
      <Version>4.2.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting">
      <Version>5.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Toolkit">
      <Version>7.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm">
      <Version>7.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Win32.Registry">
      <Version>5.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf">
      <Version>1.1.37</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Config">
      <Version>4.7.10</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="106.13.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.DirectoryServices" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reactive.Core">
      <Version>5.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reactive.Linq">
      <Version>5.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Vanara.PInvoke.Security">
      <Version>3.3.10</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="WpfAnimatedGif">
      <Version>2.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Behaviors\PasswordBehaviors.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Commands\SaveChangesCommand.cs" />
    <Page Remove="UI\UserControls\Auth\Styles.xaml" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: We don't know what files you actually do have, but from the project file, it may be that there's no real code included in the build. Do you see .cs files in the solution explorer when the project is open?

Comment: Interesting. Yes I see plenty of .cs files. And they have code in them. The project compiles but it won't debug.

Comment: Does it run outside the debugger?

Comment: Try to compare the project file to a new WPF project, and remove the settings in PropertyGroup that aren't in the new project. Maybe one of the settings is doing something silly. If that works, try figure out which setting(s) cause trouble. But I believe it's more likely something in some startup file - Program.cs, App.xaml, App.cs or something like that.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/features/host-error-codes.md

Comment: thanks @HansPassant. According to that page the problem is "Resolution of dependencies in hostpolicy failed. This can mean many different things, but in general one of the processed .deps.json contains entry for a file which could not found, or its resolution failed for some other reason (conflict for example)."